# Why is this list returning x and y in the wrong order?

Tags: python, arrays, list, grid, 2d

I have basically a 2d grid array that is created with this:

```
def createRoom(self):
    self.room = [[0] * 8 for x in xrange(8)]
    for x in xrange(8):
        self.room[x][0] = 2
        for j in xrange(8):
            self.room[0][j] = 2
            for i in xrange(8):
                self.room[-1][x] = 2
                for n in xrange(8):
                    self.room[n][-1] = 2
    for x in xrange(6):
        self.room[1][x+1] = 1
    for x in xrange(1):
        self.room[2][x+6] = 1
    for x in xrange(1):
        self.room[3][x+6] = 2
    for x in xrange(1):
        self.room[4][x+6] = 2
    for x in xrange(1):
        self.room[3][x+5] = 1
    for x in xrange(1):
        self.room[4][x+5] = 1
    for x in xrange(1):
        self.room[5][x+6] = 1
    for x in xrange(6):
        self.room[6][x+1] = 1
    for x in xrange(5):
        self.room[x+1][1] = 1               

    return self.room
```

and using PrettyPrinter it looks like this:

```
[   [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
    [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
    [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

but when I want to get self.room[6][3] it returns 1 instead of 2.

Unless I change the order to self.room[3][6], why is it doing this?

Comment: just copy that text instead of posting an image pls.

Answer (score 1):

This is your "room".  The way you've set it up, it will be 0-based indexing in row-major order.

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],   # <-- 4th row
 [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],   # <-- 7th row
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

`room[6][3]` is the 4th element in the 7th row, i.e. 1.

`room[3][6]` is the 7th element in the 4th row, i.e. 2.

Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out how much easier it is to type

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Than to type what you typed. But that aside, observe the following output, and perhaps you will understand.

```
>>> room[0]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> room[1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
>>> room[2]
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
>>> room[3]
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
>>> room[4]
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
>>> room[5]
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
>>> room[6]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
>>> room[7]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> room[6][0]
2
>>> room[6][1]
1
>>> room[6][2]
1
>>> room[6][3]
1
```

Comment: I've just deleted it all and set room to that array...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`self.room[6][3]` is 1 because that is what you set it to in the following loop:

```
    for x in xrange(6):
        self.room[6][x+1] = 1
```